# Modern Geometry: A line, PQ, parallel to base BC of triangle ABC intersects AB and AC at points P and Q, respectively.

Tags: geometry

A line $PQ$, parallel to base $BC$ of $\triangle ABC$ intersects $AB$ and $AC$ at points $P$ and $Q$, respectively. The circle passing through point $P$ and tangent to $AC$ at point $Q$ intersects $AB$ again at point $R$. Prove that points $R$, $Q$, $C$, and $B$ lie on a circle.

This is what I have so far, does this sound right??

$\angle AQP  = \angle ACB$ by corresponding angles.
$\angle QRA  = \angle AQP$ by the alternate segment theorem.
$\angle BRQ = 180^\circ – \angle QRA = 180^\circ - \angle ACB$ which implies $\angle BRQ + \angle ACB = 180^\circ$ since the sum of opposite angle $= 180^\circ$ the quadrilateral $BRQC$ is cyclic and hence lies on a circle.

Comment: Looks good to me. Another way to characterize cyclic quadrilaterals which might be more convenient here is by proving that the angle between one side and a diagonal is equal to the angle between the opposite side and the other diagonal.

Comment: Looks good to me, though you should be careful with the general position of point $R$. Your solution is based slightly on assumptions of where point $R$ lies, with respect to $P$.

Comment: Can you update my proof to show reflect your comments then please?

Comment: @Sam I think you must change $\angle QRA  = \angle AQP$ by $\angle QRA  = \angle APQ$. Edit it.